# Is it ok to catch SQL Contraint violation exceptions in program?

Tags: java, mysql, exception

This question is too basic though. But I need to know the ethical approach towards programming while dealing with database.
Say, I have a table name `Client` with its `id` column acting as a foreign key in some other table (say `Orders`).
If I try to delete a row from `Client` it would throw me a

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

Now, if I am working in production environment and constraint violation exception is thrown, is it ethical approach to catch it? Or I have to do some native coding to catch such constraints and avoid calling the delete function? I am really new to this. Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple absolute answer. It depends on the user's need.

In general, **you should catch an exception if you intend to recover and carry on with the processing**. There can be many reasons why you want to do this. For example, some errors may be *transient*, meaning that you might succeed if you wait a bit (like a network error). In this case, it's reasonable to catch the exception and try again after waiting a while. Or, if your application is a game, it might be more beneficial to continue even if there is an error (because even if your app behaves badly, it can't do serious harm - in that case, you might want to carry . on and hope the error doesn't affect the gameplay too much).

**In other situations, it's better to terminate the processing (or even the application)**. For example, if you are executing a batch job and an assertion exception happens (because the assumption you had set has been violated), then it's often better to fail the job so that one can investigate (rather than letting it continue and potentially letting wrong results go unnoticed and cause bigger issues later).

Now, coming back to your example, it depends on the context. Without knowing your context well, I might suggest to catch it and display a solution to the user ("You have to delete all orders of client X before you can delete this client!" etc). But you have to judge it for yourself based on your analysis of the business situation.

Comment: Agreed to fact that it depends on B2B situations. But my question is, is it OK to involve database server in this every time user tries to delete a row? Or should we do manage it inside our program without involving the db server? Is there even 1% chance that server ignores constraints and delete row when user triggers the query? That would be extremely worse. That's the issue I am worried about.

Comment: I think there are legitimate arguments for both. Pythonistas might argue "let it violate DB constraint and use exception for flow control". Java people might prefer checking it first. Though for the later you have to worry about race conditions. Personally, if it's simple enough I think it's ok to rely on DB constraint. When there's a bunch of conditions to satisfy, then it's probably better to explicitly check. @Sushant

Comment: Yep. Thanks for advice. I am in Java people. I will play it safe.